# Query entities wih a specific parent's property in GAE and python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is it possible in any way to query entities using one of their parent's property in GAE, like this (which doesn't work)?

```
class Car(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    type = db.StringProperty()

class Part(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()

car = Car()
car.title = 'BMW X5'
car.type = 'SUV'
car.put()

part = Part(parent = car)
part.title = 'Left door'
part.put()

parts = Part.all()
parts.filter('parent.type ==', 'SUV') # this in particular
```

I've read about *ReferenceProperty*, and *Indexes* but I'm not sure what I need.

GAE lets me set a parent to the *Part* entity, but do I need an actually (kind of duplicate):

```
parent = db.ReferenceProperty(Car, required=True)
```

That would feel like duplicating what the system does already since it has a parent. Or is there an other way?

Comment: FYI: `type` is a reserved word in Python and if you're going to think that `kind` is a good idea.. then it's also bad because kind is used in Google App Engine..

Comment: Also.. you could simply write `car = Car(title='BMW X5', type='SUV')` and then `car.put()`

Comment: type is not a reserved word in this context, it's just a pre-defined function. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an answer to your question as such, but NDB offers structured properties.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#structured

> You can structure a model's properties. For example, you can define a model class Contact containing a list of addresses, each with internal structure.

Although the structured properties instances are defined using the same syntax as for model classes, they are not full-fledged entities. They don't have their own keys in the Datastore. They cannot be retrieved independently of the entity to which they belong. An application can, however, query for the values of their individual fields.

So here car would contain parts as a structured property. If this is viable in your use case depends on how you structure your data. If you want to know what parts make up a specific car, that seems viable. If you want to filer global parts regardless of what car they belong to, then you can still do that but you'll have to make the "parts" inside each car also refer to a different model. If you see what I mean (I'm not sure I do), as each car contains it's own parts.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the parent as an explicit property isn't going to help.

You can break it up in two parts though:

```
for suv in Car.all().filter('type', 'SUV'):
  for part in Part.all(ancestor=suv):
    ...do something with part...
```

Comment: Can you clarify "Adding the parent as an explicit property isn't going to help."? Why not exactly? Do you mean that parts.filter('parent.type ==', 'SUV') wouldn't work if parent was a ReferenceProperty? (in other words that we can't access a property of a property in a filter or gql query?)

Comment: Correct. You cannot reference another entity's properties in a filter, only properties of the Model subclass you're querying.  (It's not SQL. :-)  Also AFAIK you should use 'foo =' instead of 'foo ==' if you're using this notation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to query on the property of another (parent) object, you gotta get that object first.

I can think of two solutions to your problem:

Guido's way is to query for the parent, and then query for the part.  This way issues more queries.

The second way is to store a copy of parent.type inside your Part.  The downsides are that you're storing duplicate data (more storage), and you have to be careful that your the data in Part and data in Car match up.  However, you only need to issue one query.

You'll have to figure out which one works better for you.

Comment: Yeah, duplicating the parent's type (e.g. as 'parent_type') will work.  But it costs you an extra property and an extra index, and will make all your writes cost an extra operation for updating the index, and cost you a bit extra in storage.  (The added byte count is hard to determine exactly but at least equal to the length of the property name you choose plus the length of the string plus a few bytes for fixed overhead.)